# How to update a large table in optimized way using postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql. I have a table with about 10 million of records. I need to update a column of the table say 'a' using a sequence. This column needs to be updated in the order of another column say 'b'. So, for any two records r1 and r2, if value of 'a' for r1 is less than value of 'a' for r2 then value of 'b' for r1 must be less than value of 'b' for r2.

I am using something like this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET col1 = nextval('myseq') 
WHERE key IN (SELECT key 
              FROM table 
              ORDER BY col2);
```

key is the primary key of the table.

But it is taking too much time. Can anyone help me in doing it in optimized way.

Thanks

Comment: How are the records `r1` and `r2` connected? Maybe `key` column?

Comment: Your postgresql version?

Comment: version is postgresql 8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
UPDATE table t
SET col1 = t2.new_col1 
FROM (SELECT t2.key, nextval('myseq') as new_col1
      FROM table t2
      ORDER BY t2.col2) t2 
WHERE t1.key = t2.key;
```

Or better something like:

```
UPDATE table t
SET col1 = t2.new_col1 
FROM (SELECT t2.key, 
             row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t2.col2) as new_col1
      FROM table t2) t2 
WHERE t1.key = t2.key;
```

Comment: @user1960872 An index on `col2` can speed up the query, but it still rewrites 10m of rows. + it needs to sort all 10m of rows (adding O( n*log(n) ) on top ).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use update at all.

Use a SELECT INTO like this:

```
SELECT *, nextval('myseq') AS col1
INTO new_table
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    ORDER BY key
) AS sorted
```

Then replace the old table with the new.  You'll have to recreate all your indexes and reinforce your primary keys.

Postgres doesn't replace each row it updates, it adds a second entry for the row and deprecates the old one.  So if you're doing millions of updates it will make access extremely slow.  Replacing the whole table is usually your best option.

Comment: It will cause PROBLEMS. If any foreign keys / checks / triggers / ...  present.

Comment: It may be better to use `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...`. It will be easier to read. Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html)

Comment: I have used this approach. But I don't want to create temp tables because my old table contains references to other tables.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: If there are millions of rows to update, you don't really have a choice.  The UPDATE operation will never complete.

Comment: There is little  difference between time to create a table with 1m rows or `INSERT` (or `UPDATE`) 1m rows into the existing table. The only major difference - the time to `VACUUM` the table after `UPDATE`.